# Threading with Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, python-multithreading

I need to be able to send control-c to the new thread that I start. How would I go about this. I can start the thread, but I need to stop like I do in the command line using control-c.

```
from Tkinter import *
import threading # should use the threading module instead!
import Queue
import os


def show1():
    os.system('ola_recorder -p MyRecord -i 0')

def show2 ():
    os.system('ola_recorder -p MyRecord ')

def stop ():
    os.system('^c')


t = threading.Thread(name='Show2', target=show2)

root = Tk()
b = Button(root, text="Show 1", command=lambda: thread.start_new(show1, ()))
b.pack()

b2 = Button(root, text="Show 2", command=lambda: t.start())
b2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: here's [an example how to start/stop external subprocess in Tkinter](https://gist.github.com/zed/4067619). Here's [similar example that uses threads to read subprocess' output](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288).

Comment: I looked at these examples and was able to clean up my threaded code a bit, but I still can't stop the process. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `p = Popen()` to start a subprocess and `p.terminate()` to stop it as shown in the examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the reason what you're doing doesn't work:

Each call to `os.system` just calls your platform's `system` (or `_system`, on some Windows platforms) function, which creates a brand-new shell process each time. So, there's no way you can do anything with `os.system` to affect another call.

---

If you want to send a ^C to an arbitrary process, you can do that with [`os.kill`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.kill). To make it portable, you have to do something like this:

```
def send_ctrl_c(pid):
    try:
        sig = signal.CTRL_C_EVENT
    except AttributeError:
        sig = signal.SIGINT
    else:
        os.signal(pid, sig)
```

However, you need the other process's pid to do that, and `os.system` doesn't give you that.

---

So, the right thing to do is to use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
proc2 = None

def show2():
    global proc2
    proc2 = subprocess.Popen('ola_recorder -p MyRecord', shell=True)
    proc2.wait()
```

Since there's no good reason to use the shell here, you'd probably be better off passing `Popen` a list of args, instead of a string, and leaving off the `shell=True`. And of course it would be a lot cleaner to not stick `proc2` in a global, but I'll ignore that for this toy example.

Anyway, now you can get the pid and use it:

```
def stop():
    send_ctrl_c(proc2.pid)
```

However, if you're going to do that, you might as well just use the `Popen` object directly. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) for full details of what you can do with it, but here's a quick version:

```
def stop():
    global proc2
    try:
        sig = signal.CTRL_C_EVENT
    except AttributeError:
        sig = signal.SIGINT
    proc.send_signal(sig)
```

When you call `stop`, the process will get killed exactly as if it had received a ^C (POSIX), or as close as possible to as if it had received a ^C (Windows), the `wait` call will return (with a -2, at least on POSIX), and your thread will finish as well.

---

One last note: You almost never want to use the `thread` module directly, and you do not want to reuse `threading.Thread` objects.
So, instead of this:

```
b = Button(root, text="Show 1", command=lambda: thread.start_new(show1, ()))
```

… or this:

```
b2 = Button(root, text="Show 2", command=lambda: t.start())
```

… do this:

```
def start2():
    global t2
    t2 = threading.Thread(name='Show2', target=show2)
    t2.start()
```

Of course, a non-toy program should avoid using a global, and will want to keep track of all existing threads instead of just the last one (if you're allowed to click the button while a background thread is already running), and will probably want to `join` all of its threads at quit.